# Google app engine file system returns unactual files after requesting it

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a web app deployed in google app engine.
And in one directory called "csv" there're csv files named with unique IDs. But when I try to download these files they're sometimes unavailable (about 50% of attemps).

I tried to check this "csv" folder and see how it changes after refresh. Approximately 50% of refreshes it shows all existing files and another 50% times it shows all files without the last added file. You can see the two example refreshes on screenshots:

[image: First refresh (one file missed)]

[image: Second refresh (all existing files)]

Why does this happen? What shall I do to make it always display all existing files?

Comment: What storage are these files on? How are they stored? Can you show the code obtaining the list of files?

Comment: @DanCornilescu
These files are stored simply in the client directory.
We use external module to display it: 

'app.use('/csv', express.static('./public/lib/CSVData/'), directory('./public/lib/CSVData/', {'icons':true}));'